# Enable Multiple Hosts

Tags: apache

I configured my Debian server with Apache where I listen to my api at http: // localhost or http: // localhost: 3000 and I get my jsons.
Now I would like to enable another server in www / html / uploads, where I will use it for uplodas files. How do you do it?
\
000-default.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>


# ProxyPreserveHost On

# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:
# Usage:
# ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# Example:
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/

  #ServerName localhost

   </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either write to the 000-default.conf file or create a new .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /www/html/uploads
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```